# Symfony 2 : How to check that at least one checkbox has been check when your field is based on an entity type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I build a form that allow user to choose a car from a list (of Cars entities).

The form is not mapped on any entity. How can I check that at least one checkbox has been selected ?
I tryed to add a count constraints but my form doesn't work anymore ! What's wrong with that ?  How shall I proceed ?

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Count;
```

... The form code :

```
     public function chooserAction() {
//symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html
        $cars = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('CarBundle:Car')
                ->findAll();
        $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder();

        $formBuilder->add('cars', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'CarBundle:Car',
            'property' => 'id',
            'expanded' => 'true',
            'multiple' => 'true',
            'constraints' => new Count(
                    array('min' => 1, 'max' => 3)
            )
        ));

        $formBuilder->add('save', 'submit');
        $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response("ok");
        }

        return $this->render('CarBundle:Car:chooser.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this work with `Callback` constraint - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Check for number of selected checkboxes in your callable and add violation if it is below the required minimum.